# Using Docker heredoc with Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

It's been a while since Docker introduced the ability to use heredoc in the `RUN` command, and I use it quite often.

However, when I tried to use it with Cloud Run, it seems that this feature is not supported, or do I need to do something to enable it?

Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

RUN <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -y build-essential cmake git python3 python3-pip wget zip
pip install conan
conan profile detect
EOF
```

I get the error:

> Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 13: unknown instruction: APT-GET

Comment: Do you use `docker build` anywhere in your flow? if yes use BuildKit while building (`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build`). Also check this https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/

Comment: I use docker, the snippet above works on my machine, but not on google cloud build.

Comment: AFAIK you must use `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` or `docker buildx build` while using extra features such as heredoc. Have you tested this guide? https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-push-docker-image#build_an_image_using_a_build_config_file

Comment: I am speaking about google cloud build, not docker (local), I do not control this flag. As I said, this WORKS on my machine.

Comment: I just sent you the google cloud build doc. You just need to click on the link in my latest cm. As I found out, you can setup custom build command in your `cloudbuild.yaml`

Comment: Here is the full sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/main/quickstart-build/cloudbuild.yaml

Comment: Can you share steps to reproduce the cases in details. For example, Are you sing github or inline editor and other relative information which helps to recreate

Comment: Just create a Dockerfile with the snippet that I have posted. Run docker build -t gcp . e it builds. Now try to submit it to Google Cloud Build, it fails to build on the Google Cloud.

Comment: @AliTavafi did you take the time to read it? I want to build the Docker image in the cloud, using *Google Cloud Build*. I don't want to use Docker for the build.

Comment: How you are using GCB?

Comment: Through `gcloud run deploy`, I do not want to manage GCB.

Comment: Can you provide all of your GCB config and flow?

Comment: There is nothing special https://github.com/carimbolabs/play/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yaml

Comment: You must put all details ***in your post***. You can use links for reference but your problem must be complete without requiring someone to leave the site. Links change, break, etc. which render your post useless in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on my machine, but I have also faced the same error as yours  when deployed to cloud run.. To answer your specific question

> However, when I tried to use it with Cloud Run, it seems that this feature is not supported, or do I need to do something to enable it?

From my above repro I believe that `heredoc` is still not supported by `cloud run`. And I don't think there is something else to be enabled to get it to work. As a work around you may try below script as suggested [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/#:%7E:text=So%2C%20we%20can,command%3A)

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y ...
```

Although work around is there you can still consider raising a feature  request in GCP  [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) with your use case scenario.

Comment: I tried another approach, instead of dealing with Google's broken & obsolete toolkits, I now build my image on GitHub with HEREDOCs and push to registry and set Cloud Run to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we can't expect much from Google, so I chose to build the image in GitHub Actions, push it to the registry, and then point the Run to the new image.

```
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY }}/${{ secrets.SERVICE_NAME }}:latest
    cache-from: type=gha
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

Comment: I deleted commentary in your post that is not acceptable on Stack Overflow. You rolled back my edit. My suggestion is to reconsider posting comments that can be considered rude or insulting. This is a professional forum, please help keep it so.

Comment: There is no insult, this is the reality @JohnHanley